# How to add root node of graph to queue?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I create an empty graph. Add node to empty graph i.e.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
```

Now I want to add root node to queue. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Now you have a single node, so when adding another node you will have two (so any of them can be a root node). So what is the meaning of "root node"?

Comment: Maybe you are interested on use `DiGraph` instead `Graph` (that is a directed graph)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want the graph to look like after you add a "root node"?

Comment: In general, if all you are asking is how you get a node back out... well, in networkx, `1` IS your node ID; unlike some other libraries, there isn't a separate graph node class you need to keep up with. So just add `1` to your queue. If your question is how do we _find_ the root node.. yeah, need more info.